# Steps for "for loop" in python

Tags: python, numpy, import

I want to change the steps of "for loop" based on the happening changes in the loop. For example:

```
for i in np.arange(0,l00):
     i=i*10
```

In the mentioned code loops runs 100 times, while i want i*10 makes affect on the loop and it runs 10 times! could u please guide me?

In fact, it was just a simple example, but the main problem is changing steps in loop. sth like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/dataset.txt')    
for i in np.arange(0,l00):
     if data[i,0]==5:
         i=i*5
     elif data[i,0]==10:
         i=i*10
     else:
         i=i*20
```

Comment: `data[i,0]==5` is it work !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a `while`-`if`-`break` loop:

Your:

```
for i in np.arange(0,l00):
     i=i*10
```

Would be:

```
i = 0
while True:
    if i > 100:
       break
    i = i + 10
```

And:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/dataset.txt')    
for i in np.arange(0,l00):
     if data[i,0]==5:
         i=i*5
     elif data[i,0]==10:
         i=i*10
     else:
         i=i*20
```

Would be:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/dataset.txt')  
i = 0
while True:
    if i > 100:
       break

    if data[i, 0] == 5:
        i = i + 5
    elif data[i, 0] == 10:
        i = i + 10
    else:
        i = i + 20
```

Answer (score 1):

[RTFM numpy.arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), it's the third parameter:

> *numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)*
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> start : number, optional
>
> Start of interval. The interval includes this value. The default start value is 0.
>
> stop : number
>
> End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out.
>
> **step** : number, optional  **<<------- HERE**
>
> Spacing between values. For any output out, this is the distance between two adjacent values, out[i+1] - out[i]. The default step size is 1. If step is specified, start must also be given.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpay.arange()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy-arange) Like `numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)`: (for details, follow the link)

```
>>>np.arange(0,100,10)
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
```

Here are more example:

```
>>> np.arange(3)
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.arange(3.0)
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> np.arange(3,7)
array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.arange(3,7,2)
array([3, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to numpy's arange you can just use the python's xrange to achieve what you are looking for:

```
for i in xrange(0,100,10):
  print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extended slice function of the python for it.

```
extendign slice function = f (L[start:stop:step]):

myArray = np.arange(0,l00)

increment = 10   // You an set the value of increment by if condition.
for i in myArray[0:0:increment]:
     print i
```